# Why has the OnStart() method from ServiceBase an arguments parameter?

Tags: c#, windows-services

Take the following example:

```
public static class Program {

    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        ServiceBase.Run(new DummyService());
    }

}

public class DummyService : ServiceBase {

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args) {

    }

}
```

The virtual method to override in ServiceBase passes a array of string arguments to the method body, however, when a application starts, it needs a main method which CAN already receive the startup arguments. So, what's the point of forcing the parameter to the OnStart() method signature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A single process can host multiple services. [You can pass arguments to a service when you start it.](http://bipinkarms.com/wp/passing-parameters-to-window-services/) These arguments can be different for each service and in fact for each start of a service.

[MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.onstart(v=vs.110).aspx)

> OnStart can take arguments as a way to pass data, but this usage is rare.

Comment: Wow, interesting. Thank you.